# MultiGroup Factor Analysis CFI gets better as model gets more restricted

Tags: factor-analysis, lavaan

I have 2 data sets from two different groups (GRP1 N = 130. GRP2 N = 471)
I am trying to check to see if the scale is invariant across groups but im coming up with a problem that the CFI is 
getting better as we add constraints. To keep it short I'll only include the results of the CFI and the RMSEA

I first ran the CFA for all the data combined using the code below

```
psc <- "PSC =~ X3 + X5 + X6 + X7 + X9r + X10r + Xrr"

# Fit the model Standardizing on the latent variable
fit <- cfa(psc, data = psc, meanstructure = TRUE, std.lv = TRUE)
```

Which gave me the following results

```
CFI 0.972, RMSEA = 0.062 CI (0.038 - 0.087)
```

I then ran the CFA twice on the two different groups to confirm MGCFA could be used

```
GROUP 1 CFI = 0.992, RMSEA = 0.034
GROUP 2 CFI = 0.958, RMSEA = 0.076
```

I then ran the invariant testing with the below results for CFI

```
Configural invariance 0.966
Metric Invariance 0.963
Scalar Invariance 0.967
Residual Error Invariance 0.971
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening? Is it just because my GRP1 is very small.

Comment: Can you confirm that you're using the generic ML estimator (from your code, it looks like you are)? Using a robust estimator (e.g., MLR) can sometimes cause this to happen, when the scaling parameter changes between levels of invariance. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/234232/testing-measurement-invariance-with-robust-estimators-yields-bizarre-improved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that the change in chi-square associated with increasing model constraints is not larger than the increase in the degrees of freedom associated with the addition of those constraints.

Consider the equation for calculating CFI:

$$
CFI = 1-\frac{max[(\chi_M^2-df_M),0]}{max[(\chi_M^2-df_M),(\chi_I^2-df_I),0]}
$$

where $\chi_M^2$ is the chi square statistic for the model being tested and $\chi_I^2$ is the chi square statistic for the independence model.

Note that the numerator is governed by the difference between the $\chi_M^2$ and $df_M$. Thus, if the model fit is only slightly worsened by adding constraints, the chi-square statistic may increase at a slower rate than the degrees of freedom earned by imposing said constraints. The result? A numerator that gets smaller and a CFI value that gets larger (with an upper limit of 1).

This property is the reason why CFI serves as a parsimony-adjusted fit index as it penalizes you for including paths that do not add much value in terms of reproducing the observed covariance matrix.