CFA Measurement Invariance - can weak invariance be significant with the configural but not strong invariance?
I am a newbie here. I searched through the forum but did not find similar questions, so I hope someone who is proficient with SEM / lavaan can help out.
I am using R lavaan and semTools to perform measurement invariance analysis based on the following models:
fit.original <- lavaan::cfa(model = cfa_model_expr, data = data_df, ordered = TRUE, group = "GENDER")

fit.metric <- lavaan::cfa(model = cfa_model_expr, data = data_df, ordered = TRUE, group = "GENDER", group.equal = c("loadings"))

fit.scalar <- lavaan::cfa(model = cfa_model_expr, data = data_df, ordered = TRUE, group = "GENDER", group.equal = c("loadings", "intercepts"))

Once fitted, I used semTools::compareFit to compare these three models, but I got lavaan warning that some models were not nested or less restricted model.
Warning: lavaan WARNING:
    Some restricted models fit better than less restricted models;
    either these models are not nested, or the less restricted model
    failed to reach a global optimum. Smallest difference =
    -540.550720801662
Scaled Chi-Squared Difference Test (method = “satorra.2000”)

lavaan NOTE:
    The “Chisq” column contains standard test statistics, not the
    robust test that should be reported per model. A robust difference
    test is a function of two standard (not robust) statistics.
 
             Df AIC BIC  Chisq Chisq diff Df diff    Pr(>Chisq)    
m.original 1678         3786.0                                     
m.metric   1714         4463.5     102.06      36 0.00000003094 ***
m.scalar   1836         3923.0    -717.11     122             1    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

So I proceed to use anova to do pairwise comparison:
Scaled Chi-Squared Difference Test (method = “satorra.2000”)

lavaan NOTE:
    The “Chisq” column contains standard test statistics, not the
    robust test that should be reported per model. A robust difference
    test is a function of two standard (not robust) statistics.
 
             Df AIC BIC  Chisq Chisq diff Df diff    Pr(>Chisq)    
m.original 1678         3786.0                                     
m.metric   1714         4463.5     102.06      36 0.00000003094 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Warning: lavaan WARNING:
    Some restricted models fit better than less restricted models;
    either these models are not nested, or the less restricted model
    failed to reach a global optimum. Smallest difference =
    -540.550720801662
Scaled Chi-Squared Difference Test (method = “satorra.2000”)

lavaan NOTE:
    The “Chisq” column contains standard test statistics, not the
    robust test that should be reported per model. A robust difference
    test is a function of two standard (not robust) statistics.
 
           Df AIC BIC  Chisq Chisq diff Df diff Pr(>Chisq)
m.metric 1714         4463.5                              
m.scalar 1836         3923.0    -717.11     122          1

So the culprit appears to be between m.metric and m.scalar. Then if I compare m.original and m.scalar, I got a non-significant result:
Scaled Chi-Squared Difference Test (method = “satorra.2000”)

lavaan NOTE:
    The “Chisq” column contains standard test statistics, not the
    robust test that should be reported per model. A robust difference
    test is a function of two standard (not robust) statistics.
 
             Df AIC BIC Chisq Chisq diff Df diff Pr(>Chisq)  
m.original 1678          3786                                
m.scalar   1836          3923      185.4     158    0.06715 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

It does not make sense here because that means my original model satisfied the factor loadings + intercepts invariance between groups but not factor loadings itself (weak invariance)?

UPDATE (2 May 2024): To include the summary statistics for fit.scalar below. The model converged and the model fit statistics seem to suggest an adequate fit (with scaled CFI ~ 0.96, scaled TLI ~ 0.96, scaled RMSEA ~0.065, SRMR ~ 0.055). Could this be a case of sample size issues for chi-square (I have N=699 in total, divided into 345 and 354 for group 1 and group 2)
lavaan 0.6.16 ended normally after 201 iterations

  Estimator                                       DWLS
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of model parameters                       522
  Number of equality constraints                   208

  Number of observations per group:                   
    Male                                           345
    Female                                         354

Model Test User Model:
                                              Standard      Scaled
  Test Statistic                              3922.985    4517.138
  Degrees of freedom                              1836        1836
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000       0.000
  Scaling correction factor                                  1.181
  Shift parameter                                         1196.628
    simple second-order correction                                
  Test statistic for each group:
    Male                                      2181.037    2436.694
    Female                                    1741.948    2080.445

Model Test Baseline Model:

  Test statistic                            516568.414   65863.161
  Degrees of freedom                              1806        1806
  P-value                                        0.000       0.000
  Scaling correction factor                                  8.036

User Model versus Baseline Model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    0.996       0.958
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       0.996       0.959
                                                                  
  Robust Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                            NA
  Robust Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                               NA

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.057       0.065
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.055       0.062
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.060       0.067
  P-value H_0: RMSEA <= 0.050                    0.000       0.000
  P-value H_0: RMSEA >= 0.080                    0.000       0.000
                                                                  
  Robust RMSEA                                                  NA
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower                        NA
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper                        NA
  P-value H_0: Robust RMSEA <= 0.050                            NA
  P-value H_0: Robust RMSEA >= 0.080                            NA

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

  SRMR                                           0.055       0.055

Parameter Estimates:

  Standard errors                           Robust.sem
  Information                                 Expected
  Information saturated (h1) model        Unstructured



Welcome to CV!
I asked a similar question many moons ago, and the answer I received was superb. You might find it helpful (and if not, maybe you can report back what you checked and how it appeared). And if this does provide a solution for you, consider giving tomka's  answer an upvote
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/234232/testing-measurement-invariance-with-robust-estimators-yields-bizarre-improved

Have you looked at the fit.scalar output to see if there are any issues?

Thanks @jsakaluk , I will check out the post.

Thanks @JeremyMiles, I updated my original post to show the summary of fit.scalar. One challenge I have is I am using polychoric correlation (for ordinal values - Likert scale), so some stats are not applicable such as ML-based estimator and AIC/BIC comparison.

Not what you were originally asking about but your scaled chi-square is higher than your standard chi-square. That's not unheard of, but it's weird. You might want to investigate that a bit.
That's a huge model for not huge sample sizes, it wouldn't suprise me if something went wrong.

Thank you very much @JeremyMiles for the observation. Yes, it was a 7-factor model with approximately 65-70 items. May I know if there is a tool that can estimate based on my model what is consider an adequate sample size? I am still in the process of reducing items, but hopefully I can get to stage to balance between sample size vs evaluating the psychometrics of the model.

Wang & Rhemtulla have a nice paper (https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/2515245920918253) and shiny app (https://yilinandrewang.shinyapps.io/pwrSEM/) on estimating power for SEM
